# In App Billing the same version requirement

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play

Does the final published app requires the same version for In-App Billing as the testing one:

> the version number of the uploaded application must match the version
>   number of the application you load to your device for testing

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

This would be a problem if the users with the old app versions cannot pay to unlock their demo game into the full mode, for example.

If this is the case then whoever would try to unlock his demo game should get the message to download the latest version first before the purchase, rather than an error message such as:

> "Application Error : This version of the application is not configured
>   for Market Billing. Check the help center for more information."

Any suggestions about the best way to deal with this?

Comment: I have been asking myself the same question, and I would find it very hard to believe that users with older versions can't make purchases. I'll find out soon, I guess, I'm counting on that old apps can make in app purchases.

Comment: I guess one way would be to provide IAP, but if it fails for any reason, to automatically jump to the full version app on the market. I cannot see the reason why older versions should not make IAP purchases.

Comment: @Lumis, interesting, why you didn't award your bounty to any of provided answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have going throw this every time I'm publishing a new versions of our apps. Solution is simple - just upload `apk` file with same version you are testing now (with BILLING permission, signed with your release certificate) as **draft** to your [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home). To do this click on your apps name in apps list in Developer Console, click "APK files" tab, next click "Upload APK" button, choose your new `apk` from your local computer, upload it, then click "Save" button in upload dialog, and don't forget to click another "Save" button in upper-right corner of "Edit Application" page.

After that, you will see two sections in "APK files" tab - **Active** and **New**. There will be a link "Activate" near your newly uploaded `apk` also. But **do not** click it until your will be ready to publish your new `apk` to users.

Please note, you may need to wait up to a **few hours** until new version of your `apk` will become active and *"This version of the application is not configured for Market Billing"* error message disappear.

Regarding proof for this from official sources - this information presents in a link you have provided in your question:

> Upload your application as a draft application to the publisher site.
>   You do not need to publish your application to perform end-to-end testing with real product IDs; you only need to upload your application as a draft application. However, you must sign your application with your release key before you upload it as a draft application. Also, the version number of the uploaded application must match the version number of the application you load to your device for testing. To learn how to upload an application to Google Play, see [Uploading applications](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113469&rd=1).

And I can sure you from my own experience this method is works.

Users with older versions of your app still will be able to use your app, and still will be able to buy In-App Purchases even after you will publish new version of your `apk`.

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to just use the publish apps version number in development? Thus negating all this uploading? My builds are versioned by CI so my developer version can be anything.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upload the new version of your app to the Play Store (but don't activate it). This will allow you to test IAP. Older (published) versions of your app retain the ability to use IAP. IAP does not work for versions of the app that haven't been uploaded to Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

Does the final published app requires the same version for In-App Billing as the testing one:

> You can change the application version but the package name &
>   signature should match with the application that you uploaded to the
>   Google Play market.

If this is the case then whoever would try to unlock his demo game should get the message to download the latest version first before the purchase, rather than an error message such as:

"Application Error : This version of the application is not configured for Market Billing. Check the help center for more information."

Any suggestions about the best way to deal with this?

> The Google play market rejects in-app billing from the unsigned apps.
>   You should sign the application and upload it to the Google Play
>   market. You should use the same signature for the subsequent
>   releases as well. Hope this helps.
>
> Sometimes there is some delay in Google Play synchronization. Wait for
>   around 30 mins and try again.